# MySQL performance: raw query vs. stored procedure

Tags: mysql

As I know there is know significant performance difference between raw queries and stored procedures in MSSQL (for example, query plans are cached in the same way for both). But what about MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the value in SP is not in performance, hasn't been for some time. The value in stored procedures has more to do with security and data lifespan. Take a look at the article linked here a couple of years ago - [Is this a valid benefit of using embedded SQL over stored procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002212/is-this-a-valid-benefit-of-using-embedded-sql-over-stored-procedures/1002236#1002236)